# How can I search through a filePath that I pass to My kotlin android recyclerview adapter

Tags: kotlin

I am using a File class to display Folders and files in Kotlin within a recyclerView. I don't know how to search through one like I would if I had a model class. Also, I am only able to get images/*. What would I have to write in order to get both?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxRGk.png)

Comment: Do u wanna update the screen according to user search?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: yes, I would like to know how I can search through a File(path) as I have passed it to my recyclerViews adapter